# How to inverse a log2 transformation

Tags: r, math, logarithm

I have data in this form:

```
        ds           y
1   2015-12-31 51737806366
2   2016-01-01   451800500
3   2016-01-04    48503189
4   2016-01-06      221000
5   2016-01-07   542483038
6   2016-01-08   628189789
7   2016-01-09   556762005
8   2016-01-10   195672447
9   2016-01-11   279202668
10  2016-01-12   540234196
11  2016-01-13  3403591404
12  2016-01-14   610409176
```

the values in the `y` column represent income, money units. I made an exploratory plot of this data in its original form and found the plot not too useful, the visual of the data was not appropriate, so in order to improve my visualizations I applied a `log2()` transformation to the `y` column... it worked fine:

```
        ds        y
1   2015-12-31 35.59050
2   2016-01-01 28.75111
3   2016-01-04 25.53158
4   2016-01-06 17.75369
5   2016-01-07 29.01500
6   2016-01-08 29.22663
7   2016-01-09 29.05249
8   2016-01-10 27.54387
9   2016-01-11 28.05674
10  2016-01-12 29.00901
11  2016-01-13 31.66441
```

The problem now is that in order to complete my analysis I need to get the `y` values back to their original form. Is there any way to reverse the `log2()` transformation I applied so I can get the original numbers back?

Comment: To raise a number to a power in R, you use `x ^ z`. Here, to convert that column you would do `2 ^ my_data$y` or similar.

Comment: The main problem with this is that you're changing your data instead of creating new variables (columns). Look into `mutate` of `tidyverse` on how to do that easily.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's simple.

First, call log2:

```
data$y = log2(data$y)
```

After that, if you want to have the original y back just do:

```
data$y = 2^data$y
```

The [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) is the inverse function to exponentiation.

The general rule is:

```
   logb(x) = y as by = x
```

For instance:

```
   log2(4) = 2 as 22 = 4
   log2(8) = 3 as 23 = 8
```

Comment: Thiago, your help is very much appreciated, you really made me to perfectly understand the concept. it worked just fine!! Thanks a lot!! :D

Comment: I'm happy that you got it. Fantastic!